# Inversion of control in lambda

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-stream, inversion-of-control

I am trying to convert a list into the keys of a `Map`, and having default values of null. 
 However, my code requires the creation of a `HashMap` via the new keyword that goes against the principle of Inversion of Control in Spring.

May I know if there is any right way in Spring to initialize the map in this situation?

```
convertStringToList(input).stream().collect(HashMap::new, 
             (map, value) -> map.put(value, null), Map::putAll);
```

Comment: You are taking IOC too strictly. There is nothing wrong with creating a HashMap with new.

Answer (score 5):

The Spring bean autowiring is a bit different than an instantiation of a particular implementation of-non Spring configured components. Don't be afraid of the `new` keyword and a certain implementation.

```
Map<String, String> newMap = convertStringToList(input).stream().collect(HashMap::new, 
         (map, value) -> map.put(value, null), Map::putAll);
```

This is fine since you collect the `Stream` into a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), which is an interface. The Spring has no influence to which implementation will be used on the stream collecting, thus you have to specify that `HashMap` will be used (and not `TreeMap` for instance...).

If you do...

```
 Map<String, String> a = b.stream().collect(Map::new, 
         (map, value) -> map.put(value, null), Map::putAll);
```

Here you "`Cannot instantiate the type Map`" - it needs implementation and it's not the Spring's responsibility to provide one.

Comment: Thanks everyone and Nikolas for the detailed explanation! Just curious (and for my own learning), why is it not possible to use Collections.EMPTY_MAP instead of HashMap::new? Is it because of the immutability of Collections.EMPTY_MAP?

Comment: I am sorry for the late answer. You need a `Supplier<Map<K, V>>` (`() -> new HashMap<>()` is equal to `HashMap::new`), therefore `() -> Collections.EMPTY_MAP` or better `() -> Collections.emptyMap()`. However, these are the immutable versions of the `Map` and the method `Map::putAll` would throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. Moreover, if you look at the source of the `Collections.emptyMap()`, you will see that it returns an instance of a private static class `Map.EmptyMap` which is an empty navigable and immutable map.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use manual instantiation for Spring specific beans such as repositories, services, configuration classes and such.
However, it's perfectly normal to manually instantiate instances of maps and collection classes to implement your domain logic.